# Sort contents of file in alphabetical order into a new file using methods (Java)

Tags: java, loops, file, sorting, methods

So I am trying write some code to find a way to bubble sort an existing text file that I have collected the information in a form of an array and it looks like this:

> ```
> 04/26/16  Sega 3D Classics Collection
> 07/14/16  Batman: Arkham Underworld
> 06/24/16  Tokyo Mirage Sessions #FE
> ```

Essentially I want them to be in alphabetical order and it should make a brand new file that looks like this:

> ```
> Batman: Arkham Underworld
> Sega 3D Classics Collection 
> Tokyo Mirage Sessions #FE
> ```

The problem is I do not know how to remove the date of the string that it is originally part of. I think there should be some kind of function like indexOf() like in javascript. I would assume that after the extraction of the names. Then the sorting would be the same as the one I have done for the sorting of dates.

This is the code I have done:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
  public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException{

    File file = new File("C:/Users/cyrus/Downloads/Lab 11/releasedates.txt");

    String []arr = input(file);

    output(file,arr);

    outputSort1(file, arr);
    

  }

  public static String[]input (File file) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String[]arr = new String[3];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      arr[i] = sc.nextLine();

    }
    return arr;
  }

  public static void output(File file, String[] info) throws IOException{

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:/Users/cyrus/Downloads/Lab 11/fileName.txt");
    for(String aString:info){
      writer.write(aString);
    }
    writer.close();
  }

  public static void sortByMonth(String[]info){

    String temp;

    for (int j = 0; j < info.length; j++) {
      for (int i = j + 1; i < info.length; i++) {
 
  if (info[i].compareTo(info[j]) < 0) {
    temp = info[j];
    info[j] = info[i];
    info[i] = temp;
        }
     }
    }
  }

  public static void outputSort1(File file,String[] info) throws IOException{
    sortByMonth(info);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:/Users/cyrus/Downloads/Lab 11/fileNameSorted1.txt");
    for(String aString:info){
        writer.write(aString);
    }
    writer.close();
}

public static void sortByName(String[]info){
//this isn't really finished, I am unsure on how to extract JUST the name of the games
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to sort the lines. suppose you put all the lines in a list and sort that list, before the sort, you also remove the date.
Using Java Stream 8

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("04/26/16  Sega 3D Classics Collection",
                "07/14/16  Batman: Arkham Underworld",
                "06/24/16  Tokyo Mirage Sessions #FE");
        
        List<String> newLines = lines.parallelStream()
                .map(line-> line.substring(line.indexOf(" ")))
                .sorted((line1, line2)->line1.compareTo(line2))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
newLines.forEach(System.out::println);
```